# Does this L298N H-bridge produce a PWM signal or a steady voltage as its output?

Tags: arduino, pwm, h-bridge, l298

I am wondering if these l298 h-bridge packages produce an amplification of the PWM received from the micro-controller, or if they produce a fixed voltage. let's say I was viewing the output signal on an oscilloscope.

[image: l298n]

Comment: Well, I don't see an inductor on the board.

Answer (score 2):

The L298N is simply a half-bridge driver.  It will directly translate what the input C and D tell it to do. So, if you pwm C and keep D low, you will directly apply the higher voltage/higher current PWM signal to the motor.  To reverses, simply keep input C low and PWM D.

With the motor replaced by a resistor, and just measuring the voltage you should see a nice PWM signal (unless you are operating at frequencies too fast for the L298N - like 50k Hz or more).

Once you connect the motor, you'll see some significant distortion to your signal because of the inductance of the motor - that is, it will not be a perfectly rectangular-looking PWM signal.